# How do I use HAProxy with environment variables when running as service

Tags: debian, haproxy, environment-variables, debian-jessie

I am new to Linux and are trying to configure HAProxy with environment variables. I am running Debian 8 (Jessie) and HAProxy 1.5.8 that I installed using `apt-get` as per https://haproxy.debian.net/#?distribution=Debian&release=jessie&version=1.5

Without environment variables the configuration works excellent.

I followed the instructions from [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/693895/384703) (setting the environment variable from `/etc/init.d/haproxy`)to get environment variables working but still got the 503 - Service Unavailable response.

I then looked through `/etc/init.d/haproxy` and thought that these two lines maybe changed the scope of what variables were available

```
[ -f /etc/default/rcS ] && . /etc/default/rcS
. /lib/lsb/init-functions
```

so I commented them out.

I can then start HAProxy using `sudo /etc/init.d/haproxy start`and my configuration works as I expect but when I try to run `sudo service haproxy start` I still get the 503 - Service Unavailable.

It seems to me like [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/374404/service-command-and-environment-variables) has the answer I'm looking for but I have not been able to translate the answers from there to my domain.

This is the part of the haproxy.cfg file where I'm using environment variables:

```
backend backend1
    server EnvVar ${SERVER_IP}:86 maxconn 512
```

I have also looked through some other questions here without finding a solution to my problem.

How do I set an environment variable so that it can be read by haproxy when haproxy is run as a service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out.

In `/lib/systemd/system/haproxy.service` there is a line like this

```
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/haproxy
```

I looked in `/etc/default/haproxy` and this is what it looks like:

```
# Defaults file for HAProxy
#
# This is sourced by both, the initscript and the systemd unit file, so do not
# treat it as a shell script fragment.

# Change the config file location if needed
#CONFIG="/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg"

# Add extra flags here, see haproxy(1) for a few options
#EXTRAOPTS="-de -m 16"
```

I added my environment variable there and reverted the rest of my changes and it works both when running as a service and when running it directly using `/etc/init.d/haproxy`.

This is the line I added:

```
SERVER_IP=165.88.76.44
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is right and works correctly on haproxy 1.7 - 1.8

Here a simple script to improve use for multiple haproxy files :

```
cd /etc/sysconfig

for i in haproxy_*; do 
   echo $i; 
   echo "MY_SERVER=$(hostname -i)" >> $i   
done
```

Now in Haproxy settings :

```
...
backend lochttps

   server server_name ${MY_SERVER}:60441 check ssl verify none id 1
...
```